# Azure Mobile App service query limit

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services

I came across this piece of code to increase the 50 rows default limit by azure app service query.

```
table.read(function (context) {
    context.query.take(1000);
    return context.execute();
});
```

however, this implicates all my Client side page queries (iOS and Java SDK) to the table. Setting the fetch limit to 25 no longer works obviously because it is now returning 1000 rows at a time and not 25.

My question is:
Is there a way to configure the context.query.take(1000) from the client side? meaning if I'm listing records, i want it to return 50 rows by batch. and if I'm searching the table - it should return 1000 or more.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue in the Node SDK where the maximum number of rows returned was determined by the pageSize option on the server, rather than the maxTop option. This has been resolved in version 4.0.0 of the SDK that we released today.

Upgrade to this version (`npm install azure-mobile-apps@4.0.0 --save`) and the number of rows requested by the client.

Comment: Hey Dale, quick clarification - for "number of rows requested by the client" you mean setting both MSQuery.fetchOffset and MSQuery.fetchLimit accordingly correct?

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with the iOS client, but that sounds correct - I'm guessing they correspond with the OData $skip and $top query options.

Comment: Cheers! its flying with colours. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust on both the server and client side.  Check out the HOWTO documents on learn.microsoft.com:

- [iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-ios-how-to-use-client-library#a-namepagingahow-to-configure-page-size)
- [Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-how-to-use-client-library#paging)

For the server:

**ASP.NET**:
Add `[EnableQuery(MaxTop=1000)]` to the public GetAll() method on the controller.

**Node.js**:
Set the `maxTop` value in the table definition.

Comment: Hey Adrian, whats the equivalent of this [EnableQuery(PageSize = 500)] in node.js?

Comment: In your table definition file, `table.maxTop = 500;`.